# How to export styled component from a file?

Tags: typescript, styled-components

When I use the following styled component

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const CarouselContainer = () => {
    return styled.div`
        & .slick-prev, .slick-next {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            top: 50%;
        }
        & .slick-prev::before, .slick-next::before {
            font-size: 35px;
        }
        & .slick-prev {
            left: 5%;
        }
        & .slick-next {
            right: 5%;
        }
        & .slick-slide {
            height: 371px;
            position: relative;
        }
        & .slick-slide img {
            height: 371px;
            object-fit: cover;
            object-position: 0 0;
        }
        @media all and (min-width: ${providedProps => providedProps.theme.minWidthMediumDevice}) {
            & .slick-slide {
                height: unset;
                position: unset;
            }

            & .slick-slide img {
                height: unset;
                object-fit: unset;
                object-position: unset;
            }
        }

        @media all and (min-width: ${providedProps => providedProps.theme.minWidthExtraLargeDevice}) {
            & .slick-slide {
                height: 557px;
                position: relative;
            }

            & .slick-slide img {
                height: 557px;
                object-fit: cover;
                object-position: 0 0;
            }
        }
    `;
};

export default CarouselContainer;
```

as

```
import CarouselContainer from './CarouselContainer';
...
<CarouselContainer>
...
</CarouselContainer>
```

I get the error

```
JSX element type
'StyledComponentClass<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>,
HTMLDivElement>, any,
DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>>' is
not a constructor function for JSX elements.   Property 'render' is
missing...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect that invoking the styled tag returns a component constructor. So my code wraps this component constructor with another component constructor. If I assign the result of styled to CarouselContainer directly, the code works.

Comment: From the docs: A styled React component. This is returned when you call styled.tagname or styled(Component) with styles.

Comment: Indeed, assigning the result of `styled` directly to `CarouselContainer` looks like the correct solution.  If for some reason you want to wrap the component produced by `styled` with another stateless function component, your wrapper component needs to return a JSX element, not a component type.  I.e., you should save the result of `styled` to a local variable (suppose it's called `OrigComponent`) and then return `<OrigComponent />` (or maybe you want to pass some props through).

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to define it like:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const CarouselContainer = styled.div`
  // your styles
`;

const StyledComponent = styled.div`
  // your styles
`;

export { CarouselContainer, StyledComponent };
```

and use it:

```
import { CarouselContainer, StyledComponent } from './CarouselContainer';
...
<CarouselContainer>
...
</CarouselContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Matt McCutchen said in his comment, assign the `styled.div` directly to the `CarouselContainer` variable:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const CarouselContainer = styled.div`
    ...
`;

export default CarouselContainer;
```